# How to build JGit in Eclipse (dependency errors)

Tags: eclipse, jgit

I'm trying to build the latest version of [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/).  I checked out the latest version from the Git repository.  According to the [build instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide), I installed the [dependencies](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide#Option_2%3a_Install_from_Orbit_P2_Repository) via Orbit.  I then ran `mvn clean install` which was able to compile everything and run all the tests.  So this was great, there were no errors, and I can find the compiled .jar files.

I then opened Eclipse and imported the projects into a working set.  For some reason, there are numerous errors in the build process.

Imports cannot be resolved:

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarConstants;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream;
```

And more cannot be resolved:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response;
```

I tried installing Jetty via Eclipse (Install New Software).  However, that did not resolved the issue.

Am I just not supposed to build JGit in Eclipse?  All builds and testing should be done with Maven?  I'm also confused as to why Jetty and Apache are being imported in some of these subprojects for JGit and they're not listed as dependencies of JGit on the wiki.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to install the dependencies is to use one of the target platforms, as described in [Use a Target Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide#Option_1%3a_Use_a_Target_Platform). It includes all dependencies.

As for installing from the Orbit P2 repository, the listing there was incomplete. You also need to install "Apache Commons Compress", see updated instructions:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide#Option_2:_Install_from_Orbit_P2_Repository

Jetty can not be installed from Orbit, see here for instructions:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide#JGit_HTTP_Tests

Or again, use the target platform where Jetty is also included.

Comment: I don't see an "org.eclipse.jgit.target" folder or project listed.  I searched for .target files in the entire source directory but was not able to find it.  The "Apache Commons Compress" also doesn't appear to be listed under Orbit.  I'm using: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/S20121207152029/repository/

Comment: The target project is from the egit repository. Compress was a relatively recent addition, it should be in this one: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/S20130201140822/repository/

Comment: Thanks that worked for compress.  I don't think I need/want Egit, because that is more Eclipse focused and uses JGit.Honestly, the contributor guide is quite long and mixing Egit and JGit together makes it more confusing.  For the average person (me) coming to compile it, it wasn't very clear.  Would it be possible to split it out into separate documents?  Anyway, just some feedback since I see you are a developer on it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think splitting it would make it harder for EGit contributors to get going, so I'm not sure about that. But maybe we can add the M2E nature (Maven Eclipse integration) to the JGit projects, which would result in dependencies being fetched automatically.

Comment: @firefly2442 I pushed a change to add the M2E nature, which would simplify the setup: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/10600/

Answer (score 1):

The Jetty and Compress libraries are used by part of the JGit infra, but the EGit support in Eclipse doesn't need everything that JGit has.

For example, JGit also provides a collection of command-line programs (jgit init, jgit add etc.) which are not used in Eclipse. So you need to build the 'pgm' module from MAven, but that in itself isn't used by EGit which is the UI in Eclipse. Similarly, the JGit HTTP server is useful but not required for EGit operation.

I believe the archivers are used to extract out tools via the pgm module for 'jgit archive', which extracts out the contents of a branch and generates a Zip or TGZ file on the fly.

If you don't want (or need) the pgm module (and i'd suggest possibly also avoiding the iplog as well) then you can uncomment those from the list of modules in the pom.xml file. Removing the http.server (and http.test) along with the pgm modules will probably allow you to compile without needing the Jetty and Apache compress modules.